# How can I mark a verbatim-part that is gets on it's own page with exact the proper size?

Tags: verbatim, paper-size

At the moment, I do some documentation for an old database (lucky me).
To help people (including myself) understand what it does, I list 5 entries of every table inside of `verbatim`. But some of these get quite long. As this documentation should be viewed on a screen, I don't care about paper sizes. So I would like to have an environment that has only a verbatim element as its content and has exactly the correct size.

I've tried `\usepackage{pdflscape}` with the `landscape` environment, but this gives an A4-page in landscape mode.

Is there an environment that creates a new page for its content, so that the page has exactly the correct size (+margins)?
Manual solutions, that means solutions where I have to define the size, are ok, too.

Comment: I can use `standalone` document class with a `verbbox` (`verbatimbox` package) to create a verbatim page of (seemingly) arbitrary length.  Is this the sort of thing you are seeking, or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is width, not length.

Comment: If the problem is width, not length, what stops you from using the `geometry` package to define a really wide page, while still keeping `\textwidth` at a normal setting.  That way, `verbatim` would just run off the right-hand margin, but still be visible on the wide page.

Comment: I don't want all pages to be really wide. I think that's not very nice to read. Isn't it possible to change the page width for one page only?